# Would there be any performance difference between looping every row of dataset and same dataset list form

Tags: c#, performance, list, c#-4.0, dataset

I need to loop every row of a dataset 100k times.

This dataset contains 1 Primary key and another string column. Dataset has 600k rows.

So at the moment i am looping like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsProductNameInfo.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
 {    
  for (int k = 0; k < dsFull.Tables[0].Rows.Count; k++)
   {
   }
 }
```

Now **dsProductNameInfo** has 100k rows and **dsFull** has 600k rows. Should i convert **dsFull** to a **KeyValuePaired** string list and loop that or there would not be any speed difference.

What solution would work fastest ?

Thank you.

C# 4.0 WPF application

Comment: "which is fastest" invariably depends very much on the exact scenario.  It sounds like it should be fairly just to try this both ways, and just time them?

Comment: you can suggest the fastest solution if you have idea. it does not have to be list<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be quite a few things that could be optimized not related to the looping. E.g. reducing the number of iteration would yield a lot at pressent the body of the inner loop is executed 100k * 600k times so eliminating one iteration of the outer loop would eliminate 600k iterations of the inner (or you might be able to switch the inner and outer loop if it's easier to remove iterations from the inner loop)

One thing that you could do in any case is only index once for each table:

```
var productNameInfoRows = dsProductNameInfo.Tables[0].Rows
var productInfoCount = productNameInfoRows.Count;
var fullRows = dsFull.Tables[0].Rows;
var fullCount = fullRows.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < productInfoCount; i++)
 {
  for (int k = 0; k < fullCount; k++)
   {
   }
 }
```

inside the loops you'd get to the rows with `productNameInfoRows[i]` and `FullRows[k]` which is faster than using the long hand I'm guessing there might be more to gain from optimizing the body than the way you are looping over the collection. Unless of course you have already profiled the code and found the actual looping to be the bottle neck

**EDIT** After reading your comment to Marc about what you are trying to accomplish. Here's a go at how you could do this. It's worth noting that the below algorithm is probabalistic. That is there's a 1:2^32 for two words being seen as equal without actually being it. It is however a lot faster than comparing strings.
The code assumes that the first column is the one you are comparing.

```
//store all the values that will not change through the execution for faster access
 var productNameInfoRows = dsProductNameInfo.Tables[0].Rows;
 var fullRows = dsFull.Tables[0].Rows;
 var productInfoCount = productNameInfoRows.Count;
 var fullCount = fullRows.Count;
 var full = new List<int[]>(fullCount);


 for (int i = 0; i < productInfoCount; i++){
     //we're going to compare has codes and not strings
     var prd = productNameInfoRows[i][0].ToString().Split(';')
               .Select(s => s.GetHashCode()).OrderBy(t=>t).ToArray();
     for (int k = 0; k < fullCount; k++){
         //caches the calculation for all subsequent oterations of the outer loop
         if (i == 0) {
             full.Add(fullRows[k][0].ToString().Split(';')
                      .Select(s => s.GetHashCode()).OrderBy(t=>t).ToArray());
         }
         var fl = full[k];
         var count = 0;
         for(var j = 0;j<fl.Length;j++){
             var f = fl[j];
             //the values are sorted so we can exit early
             for(var m = 0;m<prd.Length && prd[m] <= f;m++){
                 count += prd[m] == f ? 1 : 0;
             }
         }
         if((double)(fl.Length + prd.Length)/count >= 0.6){
             //there's a match
         }
     }
 }
```

**EDIT** your comment motivated me to give it another try. The below code could have fewer iterations. Could have is because it depends on the number of matches and the number of unique words. A lot of unique words and a lot of matches for each (which would require a LOT of words per column) would potentially yield more iterations. However under the assumption that each row has few words this should yield substantial fewer iterations. your code has a N*M complexity this has N+M+(matches*productInfoMatches*fullMatches). In other words the latter would have to be almost 99999*600k for this to have more iterations than yours

```
//store all the values that will not change through the execution for faster access
var productNameInfoRows = dsProductNameInfo.Tables[0].Rows;
var fullRows = dsFull.Tables[0].Rows;
var productInfoCount = productNameInfoRows.Count;
var fullCount = fullRows.Count;

//Create a list of the words from the product info
var lists = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<List<int>, List<int>>>(productInfoCount*3);
for(var i = 0;i<productInfoCount;i++){
    foreach (var token in productNameInfoRows[i][0].ToString().Split(';')
                          .Select(p => p.GetHashCode())){
        if (!lists.ContainsKey(token)){
            lists.Add(token, Tuple.Create(new List<int>(), new List<int>()));
        }
        lists[token].Item1.Add(i);
    }
}
//Pair words from full with those from productinfo
for(var i = 0;i<fullCount;i++){
    foreach (var token in fullRows[i][0].ToString().Split(';')
                          .Select(p => p.GetHashCode())){
        if (lists.ContainsKey(token)){
            lists[token].Item2.Add(i);
        }
    }
}

//Count all matches for each pair of rows
var counts = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
foreach(var key in lists.Keys){
    foreach(var p in lists[key].Item1){
        if(!counts.ContainsKey(p)){
            counts.Add(p,new Dictionary<int, int>());
        }
        foreach(var f in lists[key].Item2){
            var dic = counts[p];
            if(!dic.ContainsKey(f)){
                dic.Add(f,0);
            }
            dic[f]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh i see your point. you are suggesting to compare hashcodes not strings. Well i can try 64 bit hashcode as you said. Not a bad idea :) But i believe that the nature of nested loops are the main cause of the slowness not string comparison.

Answer (score 2):

In the exact scenario you mentioned, the performance would be the same except converting to the list would take some time and cause the list approach to be slower.  You can easily find out by writing a unit test and timing it.

I would think it'd be best to do this:

```
// create a class for each type of object you're going to be dealing with
public class ProductNameInformation { ... }
public class Product { ... }

// load a list from a SqlDataReader (much faster than loading a DataSet)
List<Product> products = GetProductsUsingSqlDataReader(); // don't actually call it that :)

// The only thing I can think of where DataSets are better is indexing certain columns.
// So if you have indices, just emulate them with a hashtable:
Dictionary<string, Product> index1 = products.ToDictionary( ... );
```

Here are references to the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) and [ToDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277.aspx) concepts that you may or may not be familiar with.

The real question is, why isn't this kind of heavy processing done at the database layer?  SQL servers are much more optimized for this type of work.  Also, you may not have to actually do this, why don't you post the original problem and maybe we can help you optimize deeper?

HTH

Comment: I disagree about list necessarily being slower; firstly, you could load the list without using a DataSet at all - which will actually be faster; and second, access into a DataTable is rather circuitous - plain objects are far more direct. So objects could well be faster. Equally, for bulk processing that outweighs the initial data transepfer overhead, doing the thinking at an app-server can be nth faster and more scalable. But yes: doing it at the DB should at least be considered.

Comment: i am doing massive clustering. I suppose working on object level would be faster than database level. But as Marc Gravell said i am going to try KeyValuePaired  list. Actually my aim was getting your ideas about what structure would be fastest for looping. There could be other than string lists that i could try don't know :D

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree that if you loaded the list from a DataReader, that would certainly be faster than loading the dataset, then processing that list might be slightly faster.  But in this case, the DataSet is already created it sounds like, and he's asking if taking the further step of turning that into a list would be faster.  I think that specific scenario is provably slower.

Comment: @MarcGravell I think the objects vs. DataTable record speed argument is true.  The DataTable has to resolve the property you're looking for from its internal list / hashtable, but C# might be clever enough to optimize that at compile time and factor out the loop invariant column name lookups.  Of course he could just use column index in the first place.  Even then though, I think you're still right because this isn't a strongly typed dataset so he'd probably incur a cast penalty for each field.  So yea, a list of objects should be faster if he doesn't load it from the dataset each time.

Comment: @Millimetric not to mention the fact that given a row and column-index, it needs to: find the DataColumn (by index); obtain the inner (typed) array; fetch the value from the array (by row offset); etc - and probably a DbNull check in there somewhere.

Comment: The first init is not even to be mentioned because it is nothing to be compared. The loops taking like 5 days to complete when it is single threaded. I just recently made it multithreaded and split it to 6 times which of course becoming 6 times faster since i have 8 cores. But i am trying further optimization since it is really taking huge time and i don't have that much time. This is about my thesis project for graduating from computer engineering master degree program.

Comment: Wow!!! 5 days!!!  You absolutely must either do it at the database layer or at least change to a generic list like I updated my answer to show.

Comment: There is no way to do comparison at database. I need to compare each row with all of the other rows and if passes threshold save store them till all ends and further process and update result at the database. As i said the first init is nothing. It does not even take a minute. So i am not trying to optimized first init :) Though if you are interested in i can explain you in a chat.

Comment: Well, lay out the overall problem in another question and link it here, I can try to take a look there and give you some performance advice.  Nothing should ever take 5 days :)

Answer (score 1):

If performance is the critical factor, then I would suggest trying an array-of-struct; this has minimal indireaction (DataSet/DataTable has quite a lot of indirection). You mention KeyValuePair, and that would work, although it might not necessarily be my first choice. Milimetric is right to say that there is an overhead if you create a DataSet first and *then* build an array/list from tht - however, even then the time savings when looping may exceed the build time. If you can restructure the load to remove the DataSet completely, great.

I would also look carefully at the loops, to see if anything could reduce the actual work needed; for example, would building a dictionary/grouping allow faster lookups? Would sorting allow binary search? Can any operations be per-aggregated and applied at a higher level (with fewer rows)?

Comment: Now let me tell you what i am doing. I am comparing dataset each row with all other each rows and calculating distinct matrix between each row. Now i am only looking 1 column at each row. That column contains words split by ";" . So lets say 2 row contains 3 same word out 5 words the DM of that row is becoming 0.60 since 3 out of 5 is same. My threshold also 0.6 so i say that 2 rows compose a cluster pair and i save them in a dictionary. And the inner loop continue for that outer row until all the rows compared. and then next outer row starts. And i sent you an email via google plus.

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the data inside the nested loop?

Is the source of your datasets a SQL database? If so, the best possible performance you could get would be to perform your calculation in SQL using an inner join and return the result to .net.

Another alternative would be to use the dataset's built in querying methods that act like SQL, but in-memory.

If neither of those options are appropriate, you would get a performance improvement by retrieving the 'full' dataset as a DataReader and looping over it as the outer loop. A dataset loads all of the data from SQL into memory in one hit.  With 600k rows, this will take up a lot of memory! Whereas a DataReader will keep the connection to the DB open and stream rows as they are read.  Once you have read a row the memory will be reused/reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Comment: thanks but i have to have nested loops. as i said the first init is not important. i migrated the 600k rows dataset to list. software is using a lot of memory right now (2,3 GB) but i have 16 gb ddr3

Comment: What database(s) and versions are you using?  And what sort of thing are you doing inside your inner loop?  Is it a matching exercise, a calculation or something else?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2008 R2. This is the comparison row 1 "car;playschool;first;baby;kid;"  - row 2 "baby;king;first;car;cut;"  -   so comparison result is 3 sames out of min 5 = 0.60 and i multiply it with 100 = 60. Since my threshold is 60 i say that row 1 & 2 makes a cluster and hold it at a dictionary and continue inner loop till all inner loop finishes. when finished i update a column at database saying that row 1 made cluster pairs with following rows and the next outer loop starts

Comment: I think your best bet would be to normalise your tags: in s (sorry keep submitting comment by accident.. Will write another answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment reply to my earlier answer you said that both datasets are essentially lists of strings and each string a delimited list of tags effectively.  I would first look to normalise the csv strings in the database.  I.e. Split the CSVs, add them to a tag table and link from the product to the tags via a link table.

You can then quite easily create a SQL statement that will do your matching according to the link records rather than by string (which be more performant in it's own right).

The issue you would then have is that if your sub-set product list needs to be passed into SQL from .net you would need to call the SP 100k times.  Thankfully SQL 2008 R2, introduced TableTypes.  You could define a table type in your database with one column to hold your product ID, have your SP accept that as an input parameter and then perform an inner join between your actual tables and your table parameter.. I've used this in my own project with very large datasets and the performance gain was massive.

On the .net side you can create a DataTable matching the structure of the SQL table type and then pass that as a command parameter when calling your SP (once!).

This article shows you how to do both the SQL and .net sides. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2112/table-value-parameters-in-sql-server-2008-and-net-c/

Comment: I don't make sense to have to achieve what i am doing with this. Thanks for answer though.